# Convergent sequence to make function converge to 0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, functions

Let $f∶(0,∞)→R$ be a continuous function, and suppose that $f(1/n)=(-1)^n$ for all n∈N. Prove that there exists a sequence ${a_n }$ such that $f(a_n )=0$ for all $n∈N$ and $lim_{n→∞}⁡(a_n )=0$.

This seems like it should be a simple problem, but I am not seeing how any sequence will make this function $f$ converge to 0? Can someone explain what $f(1/n)=(-1)^n$ is saying, and how it can be manipulated using $a_n$ to converge to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $f(\frac{1}{n}) = (-1)^n$ means just what it says: it defines $f$ on all points which are equal to $\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n$: $f(\frac{1}{2}) = (-1)^2$, $f(\frac{1}{3}) = (-1)^3$, $f(\frac{1}{4}) = (-1)^4$, etc.

The intermediate value theorem is your friend here. If we look at an odd $n$, then $n+1$ is even. This means that if n is odd then $f(\frac{1}{n}) = (-1)^n = -1$, while $f(\frac{1}{n+1}) = (-1)^{n+1} = 1$. By continuity of $f$, and the fact that $0$ is between $-1$ and $1$, the IVT tells us that there is a point (call it $a_n$) in between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$ where $f(a_n) = 0$. If $n$ is even, the signs of $f(\frac{1}{n})$ and $f(\frac{1}{n+1})$ are reversed, but we can do the same thing. Since this works for all $n$, and the $a_n$ must go to $0$ (since they are between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$, which go to $0$) we have the sequence that the question asks for.